# School Online Lessons

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19, school

I go to a private school but I am funded by the council and I had covid a few weeks ago and they refused to give online lesson because "that is not what we do" is that true? Also to note is that I go to a school in England.

Comment: [This document](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/remote-education-temporary-continuity-direction-explanatory-note) appears to be on point, but I'm not familiar enough with UK terminology to interpret it with any confidence.

Comment: It says "state-funded, school-age children" so is that state-funded **or** school-age children or is it only if it is state-funded and the child is of school-age?